# Which ODE solver in Matlab allows me to advance in just one timestep only

Tags: matlab, ode

[t,y] = odeXX(odefun,tspan,y0)

I have a solver odeXX, and the `tspan = [0 0.0001]`. It seems that for any ode solver in MATLAB, they integrate by breaking `tspan` into multiple steps (some adaptive like ode45 and some non-adaptive). But I am looking for the most primitive one--just integrate from `0` to `0.0001` in one step. Which ode solvers allow me to do this and how to specify this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549238/how-do-i-force-ode45-to-take-steps-of-exactly-0-01-on-the-t-axis

Comment: @yohbs no i am not taking constant steps. I just want to take one step.

Comment: What's the difference? You're just making a constant *step* instead of *steps*. Run `ode45` with a constant step that's equal to your end time and you're done.

Comment: From messing around (MATLAB R2014b) it looks like you can get one step on e.g. ODE45 by setting `RelTol`,`AbsTol`,`InitialStep` and `MaxStep` large enough. This results in 7 function evaluations

Comment: Why do you want to do this?.

Comment: @yohbs the answers to that question do not accomplish what diff is asking for.

Comment: @David Ketcheson there is a similar function in scipy that integrate one step at a time `ODE.integrate(..., step=1)` where `ODE` is imported from `scipy.integrate.ode`

Comment: @David Ketcheson i want to evaluate in one step as i want to check the result after integration in one step (e.g. `ODE.y`) and do things according to that result. So I have to manually use `step = 1`.

Comment: But *why* do you want to check it after one step, rather than checking it after a fixed time interval?  I believe that if you explain what you really want to do, then there will be a more useful way to accomplish it.

Comment: @David Ketcheson I am checking it after a fixed time interval. But want to do it in one step in ode solver from the start of the fixed time interval to the end of fixed time interval. Taking multiple steps, as in ode45, is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking for a method that solves $x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$, $x(0)=x_{0}$ with only one evaluation of $f$ or are you willing to evaluate $f$ at multiple points?  How accurate a solution do you need?

Although MATLAB's built-in solvers with adaptive step sizes won't do this for you, it's trivial to implement your own method.  e.g. Euler's method is simply $x_{1}=x_{0}+hf(t_{0},x_{0})$.  Implementing RK4 isn't much harder.

Comment: or take this one... https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29851-runge-kutta-4th-order-ode/content/Runge_Kutta_4.m

Comment: i want to evaluate in one step as i want to check the result after integration in one step and do things according to that result. So I have to manually use step = 1.

Comment: If you're interested in stopping the simulation as soon as the system reaches a particular state (e.g. when x(t)=0), MATLAB's ODE solvers have a built-in feature for "ODE Event Location" that does this.

Comment: @Brian Borchers not only that. I want to do multiple things to the output at each "step" and update the `ODE.y` (as in scipy) and carry on the `ODE.integrate(..., step=1)` again. So I cannot afford to do this in ode45, which takes multiple steps so it is time-consuming.