# Convert scipy integration with one step to matlab integration

Tags: matlab, ode, scipy

Scipy integration allows us to do ode integration one adaptive timestep at a time and do something to it. However, matlab ode needs us to specify a [timespan](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_tspan) , and determine the adaptive timestep within, but cannot do things within.

From scipy

```
ODE.set_initial_value(y0, tlist[0])
numoftimes = len(tlist)
for ii in range(1, numoftimes):
    # while loop up to tlist[ii]
    while ODE.t < tlist[ii]:
        t_prev = ODE.t
        y_prev = ODE.y            
        # integrate up to tlist[ii], one step at a time.
        ODE.integrate(tlist[ii], step=1)
        #do something to the output
        ...
```

However, in matlab, I failed to do this, mainly `step=1` is not available.
[Which ODE solver in Matlab allows me to advance in just one timestep only](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25448/which-ode-solver-in-matlab-allows-me-to-advance-in-just-one-timestep-only)

Attempt is to make the tspan extremely small in matlab ode suite. But this is then not adaptive. In some region the original ode timestep is very big (non-stiff), but at some regions the ode timestep is very small (stiff).

```
tlist = [0 tf]    
numoftimes = len(tlist)
for ii = 1:numoftimes
     # while loop up to tlist(ii)
     while t_prev < tlist(ii)
            t_prev = T(end,:)
            y_prev = Y(end,:)           
            # integrate up to tlist(ii), one step at a time.
            t    = [t_prev,t_prev+0.0000000000001];
            [T, Y] = ode45(dydt, t, y);
            #do something to the output
            ...
     end
end
```

This then is not good as I have, even if the ode45 does integrate with only 1 step
1. force the timestep to be fixed interval
2. time-consuming as in some non-stiff region the "original adaptive" timestep needs not be that small.

How can I solve this with matlab ode suite?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with this? This seems like a case of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem, and you haven't answered this in your other question either. If I were to guess, you should use dense output functionality (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_tspan), but I really can't tell.

Comment: I am trying to do something to my output, which is then fed into the ode solver at one timestep later. I hope to do this at every adaptive timestep, which changes according to stiffness.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd say it's probably not altogether correct to call what you have an "ODE". You can do this easily, though, whatever it is, by implementing the time-stepping yourself (it's quite easy for typical methods).

Comment: but i can do this in scipy. I want to know how to do this in ode matlab suite. Also, the time-stepping from the ode solver is intended to reduce time for non-stiff region and increase accuracy for stiff-region. How can I implement adaptive time step myself?